# How can I add a bluetooth device in Juno?

Tags: bluetooth, release-juno

I cannot seem to be able to add new bluetooth device to Elementary Juno with stock utils. (with blueman it is a breeze).
Is there something wrong with my machine or is it a conscious decision (hard to believe) ?

[image: + icon in mysteriously missing]

[image: (yes, i am an administrator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I connected my phone with my computer by just hitting the connect button that you can see beside the device name in the bluetooth settings. You will have to pair it first, though.[image: Screenshot of connected device]

Comment: True that. After restart i tried again, and my unpaired device appeared there, probably just a glitch. Thank you, @Aprameya